# Android calculate waiting time on taxi app

Tags: android

Android onlocationchanged return different value even there is no moment.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}
```

Comment: Add more description to make it easier to understand

Comment: What is want is, i'm developing taxi app on android. when driver app moving i need calculate real time distance and if vehicle stop then need to calculate waiting time.

Comment: @ayeshdon if you want to calculate the waiting time, perhaps the easier way to do is to have a default timestamp, and on locationChanged, get the difference between the initial timestamp and the current timestamp. Also, after that update the initialTimestamp to the Current timestamp.

Comment: Thanks. but when vehicle is stop still there is location update happen. how can i clearly know vehicle is stop

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, location provided by Android location manager is not 100% accurate, Network based locations can have very bad accuracy > 1000m and in this case you might receive different lat/lon while you are stationary.

*We define horizontal accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude, and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then there is a 68% probability that the true location is inside the circle.
This accuracy estimation is only concerned with horizontal accuracy, and does not indicate the accuracy of bearing, velocity or altitude if those are included in this Location.*

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()

Comment: What is want is, i'm developing taxi app on android. when driver app moving i need calculate real time distance and if vehicle stop then need to calculate waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

**To get the distance between 2 location**

```
public static double distance(LatLng start, LatLng end){
      try {
          Location location1 = new Location("locationA");
          location1.setLatitude(start.latitude);
          location1.setLongitude(start.longitude);
          Location location2 = new Location("locationB");
          location2.setLatitude(end.latitude);
          location2.setLongitude(end.longitude);
          double distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
          return distance;
       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
     return 0;
  }
```

**calculate the waiting time when you want**

```
 public void startWaitTimer() {
            canceltimer();
            handlerTimer = null;
            handlerTimer = new Handler();
            handlerTimer.post(runnableTimer);
  }

    public void canceltimer() {
        if (handlerTimer != null) {
            handlerTimer.removeCallbacks(runnableTimer);
        }
    }


  public Runnable runnableTimer = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                MillisecondTime = MillisecondTime + 1000;

                UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;

                Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);

                tempSecond = Seconds;

                Minutes = Seconds / 60;

                Seconds = Seconds % 60;

                hourtime = Minutes / 60;

                MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 1000);

                tvWaitingTime.setText(String.format(locale, "%02d", hourtime) + ":" + String.format(locale, "%02d", Minutes) + ":" + String.format(locale, "%02d", Seconds));

                handlerTimer.postDelayed(runnableTimer, 1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `speed` on Location payload.

The return value is meter per seconds

[1.3 mean](https://www.google.com/search?q=meter%20per%20seconds%20to%20kilometer%20per%20hour&oq=mete&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59l2j35i39j69i61j69i60l2.1340j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

```
If(payload.speed <= 1.3) {
     //used stopwatch for calculate total waiting time 
} else {
     //calculate distance
}
```

**GIVE ME YOUR FEEDBACK**